# Update tableau sheet with last two fiscal weeks when fiscal year changes

Tags: mysql, visualization, tableau-api

I have a tableau sheet in which I need to find the number of orders that I received in the previous week and the week before that. I am able to do that with two simple calculations:

1. Get Last two weeks :(used in Filter with 1 as selection)

   IF [f_Year] = [maxyear] and [f_week] < [maxweek] AND [f_week] >= [maxweek] -2 and      [maxweek] > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
2. Count of total orders:(used in the Marks pane)

   COUNTD(IF [f_week] >= [maxweek]-2 AND [f_week]< maxweek and [f_Year]=maxyear THEN [order_id] END)

**maxyear = the maximum of all the year values(i.e current fiscal year)**

**maxweek = maximum of all the week values(i.e current fiscal week)**

**f_year = fiscal year, f_week = fiscal week.**

The fiscal year runs from February to February. I get this data from a sql database.

The problem is that when the year changes from 2015 to 2016, I will have a problem retrieving the order details for 51st and 52nd weeks of year 2015. This is because 
the above calculation would not work in two cases. First, when the current fiscal week = 1 and Second, when the current fiscal week = 2.

I also tried hardcoding the calculation (used in the filter pane):

```
IIF([maxweek] > 2, [f_Year] = [maxyear] AND [f_week] < [maxweek] AND [f_week]    >= [maxweek] -2 ,
IIF([maxweek] = 2, ([f_Year] = [maxyear] OR  [f_Year] = [maxyear]-1) AND   ([f_week] = 52 or [f_week] = 1),
[f_Year] = ([maxyear] - 1) AND [f_week] = 51 OR [f_week] = 52))
```

With the above calculation when the maxweek = 2, its returning the 1st fiscal week from both 2015 and 2016. I need the 1st fiscal week only from 2016.

How can I modify my above calculations so that even if the fiscal year changes the table remains intact with the values from the last year's fiscal weeks.

Comment: You will have to handle this with IF ELSE Clause . If Current_week = 1 or 2 Then fiscal_year = current_year-1 and fiscal_week = 52 or 51(hardcoded). This has to be done as hard-code basis because fiscal_week is non-linear as it changes from 52 to 1 in next cycle. you can't expect linear maths to solve this .

Comment: Do I need to use this hardcoded part as a separate calculation? Tableau is throwing error if I include this hardcoded part in my Get Last Two Weeks calculation field as it is expecting a boolean value after "then"

Comment: It will be difficult here without data / calc. to validate . If you can share any public link, then I might be able to show .

Comment: I modified my question with the hardcoded logic.

Comment: It will be difficult without any sample to work upon. Formula point of view you **seem** correct , But I cannot verify correctness .